# SortableJS : Build tree with drag and drop feature with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, sortablejs

I need to build a Drag N Drop functionality in VueJS 2 using Sortable.js. And I've these conditions :

1. I have to use the v-table for this, no divs allowed
2. Have to build up the tree and Drag N Drop functionality using flat tructure like below.
3. It is guaranteed that the child will follow its parent like below.

```
[
  { id: 1, depth: 0 },
  { id: 2, depth: 0 },
  { id: 3, parent: 2, depth: 1 },
  { id: 4, depth: 0 },
  { id: 5, parent: 4, depth: 1 },
  { id: 6, parent: 4, depth: 1 },
  { id: 7, parent: 6, depth: 2 },
]
```

Now I've seen some working examples/demo of Sortable.js and found that it works with a parent/child structure like below not the flat one.

```
[
 {
   "id": "0001",
   ....
   "children": [
       {
         "id": "0003",
         ....
         "children": [
           {
             "id": "0004",
             ....
             "depth": 2
           },
           {
             "id": "0006",
             ....
             "depth": 2
           }
         ],
         "depth": 1
       },
       {
         "id": "0005",
         ....
         "depth": 1
       }
   ],
   "depth": 0
 },
 {
   "id": "0002",
   ....
   "depth": 0
 }
]
```

I tried many ways but not able to get the result. Is there any way to get the result ? Am I missing some documentation to get what I want ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convert your flat json array to the one that works with sortableJs?

Comment: `{ id: 7, parent: 6, depth: 1 }` wouldn't that be depth:2 since its parent is depth:1?

Comment: Yes @Bravo you are correct. I updated the structure.

Comment: @Riddhesh no, I just want to use it for my tree. Also my items can get into thousands or maybe more. So calculating the whole tree in UI to convert it into the structure that sortable.js work will be bad idea.